# Issue with Parse: outstanding network connection.

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, parse-platform

I have encountered an outstanding network connection error while trying to run my application. I have attach the logcat below to see the messages I am getting.

Essentially, I am trying to populate a page that would display various information from the parse database about a user such as name, age, and profile picture.

```
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 11753
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753): java.lang.RuntimeException: This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at com.parse.ParseQuery.checkIfRunning(ParseQuery.java:204)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at com.parse.ParseQuery.findInBackground(ParseQuery.java:629)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at com.dooba.beta.Fragment1.setConversationsList(Fragment1.java:148)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at com.dooba.beta.Fragment1.onActivityCreated(Fragment1.java:71)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:958)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-18 15:14:58.973: E/AndroidRuntime(11753):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-18 15:15:06.893: I/Process(11753): Sending signal. PID: 11753 SIG: 9
```

Below is the complete code

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

    public interface Constants {
        String LOG = "com.dooba.beta";
    }

    private String currentUserId;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> namesArrayAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> names;
    private ArrayList<String> age;
    private ArrayList<String> headline;
    private ArrayList<String> activityname;

    private ArrayList<Images> alProfilePicture;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private Button logoutButton;
    String userGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("Gender");
    String activityName = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("ActivityName");
    Number maxDistance = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber(
            "Maximum_Distance");
    String userLookingGender = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString(
            "Looking_Gender");
    Number minimumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Minimum_Age");
    Number maximumAge = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Maximum_Age");
    Number userage = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getNumber("Age");

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        setConversationsList();

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container,
                false);

        return view;
    }

    private void setConversationsList() {
        currentUserId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getObjectId();
        names = new ArrayList<String>();
        age = new ArrayList<String>();
        headline = new ArrayList<String>();
        activityname = new ArrayList<String>();

        alProfilePicture = new ArrayList<Images>();

        // String userActivitySelectionName = null;

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();

        // query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName",userActivitySelectionName);

        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                .getObjectId());
        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
        query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
        query.setLimit(1);
        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
        // query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("Age", minimumAge);
        // query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("Age", maximumAge);
        query.orderByDescending("Name");

        Log.d(Constants.LOG, "");




        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseUser> objects,ParseException e) {

                for(int i=0;i<objects.size();i++){
                    // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
                    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");

                    ParseFile image = objects.get(i).getParseFile("ProfilePicture");


                    ParseImageView imageView = (ParseImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profilePictureResult);

                     // The placeholder will be used before and during the fetch, to be replaced by the fetched image
                     // data.
                     imageView.setPlaceholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile_pict));
                     imageView.setParseFile(image);
                     imageView.loadInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                       @Override
                       public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
                         Log.i("ParseImageView",
                             "Fetched! Data length: " + data.length + ", or exception: " + e.getMessage());
                       }


                 });
                }
    }//for loop
            });


        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistname, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistname.size(); i++) {
                        names.add(userlistname.get(i).get("Name").toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistname);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_item,
                            names);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
                }
            });


            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

            public void done(List<ParseUser> userlistheadline, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < userlistheadline.size(); i++) {
                        headline.add(userlistheadline.get(i).get("Headline")
                                .toString());
                    }
                    usersListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                            R.id.userlistheadline);
                    namesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.user_list_all,
                            headline);
                    usersListView.setAdapter(namesArrayAdapter);

                    usersListView
                            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a,
                                                        View v, int i, long l) {
                                    openConversation(names, i);
                                }
                            });

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error loading user list", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void openConversation(ArrayList<String> names, int pos) {
        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("Name", names.get(pos));
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
            public void done(List<ParseUser> user, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity()
                            .getApplicationContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("RECIPIENT_ID", user.get(0).getObjectId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error finding that user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, as I am incredibly stuck on this.
Thanks in advance and if you need any clarification, let me know.

Comment: Maybe you should try a mediocre network connection.  :-)

Comment: thanks for your response, and out of curiosity, how would i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.

It sounds like `ParseQuery` doesn't support multiple concurrent find requests.`setConversationsList()` reuses the same query instance to execute 3 background requests. Since you aren't changing the query for each of the requests, you can probably handle everything in a single `FindCallback`.

Note: Breaking this method into sub-methods would make the code easier to read and debug.

Edit:

Every handler starts with a look over the list argument and calls `get()` on each object, just with a different argument.

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {
    //...
    users.get(i).get("XXXX")
    //...
}
```

I would expect you to be able to call `get()` for each of the different arguments within a single call back. Once you collect all the information, then you can update the UI.

```
for (ParseUser user : users) {
    //...
    user.get("AAA")
    user.get("BBB")
    user.get("CCC")
    //...
}
```

You can also use the for-each loop instead of calling `users.get(i)` every time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How would I handle everything in a single FindCallback since I have tried this before but had issues resolving it.